# Dart Error: error: import of dart:mirrors is not supported in the current Dart runtime using flutter 2.0.2

Tags: flutter, dart

According to this documentation https://dart.dev/get-dart,
it is written in bold that As of Flutter 1.21, the Flutter SDK includes the **full Dart SDK.**

I know dart:mirrors has been removed from the dart shipped with the flutter sdk but this sentence above says that the **full** dart SDK is included. So how to enable dart:mirrors ?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, the full Dart SDK *is* included. That doesn't mean that you're allowed to *use* everything from the Dart SDK for a Flutter project (i.e., one whose `pubspec.yaml` file depends on Flutter).  It just means that you don't need to download and install a separate copy of the Dart SDK for non-Flutter projects.

Answer (score 5):

The `dart:mirrors` package is not available with flutter.

Do check these conversations on [google groups](https://groups.google.com/g/flutter-dev/c/ZmX5gZHhU24) and [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/1150) for more info.

An alternative package called [reflectable](https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable) is available for reflection, however it has limitations at this time.

Comment: I suspected this. But when I read As of Flutter 1.21, the Flutter SDK includes the full Dart SDK. in bold, it made me feel they changed something. Full Dart SDK includes dart:mirrors as from my perspective

Comment: I understand and I hope there is a solution to this issue. I couldn't find a solution to enabling mirrors, please do share the workaround if you have more success :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use this package in `pub.dev` [LINK](https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable)